# update listview cells/items whose index may change

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, broadcastreceiver, baseadapter

I have elements in a listview that change the way they look based on a network response

by the time the network responds the listview item (or item in the arraylist) could be at a different index

What I can do:
Make an alternate api call back to the server which returns all the items in the list (in their most updated form), and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter

but this seems like a waste of processes, and so does some alternative of searching an arraylist for the equivalent object, updating it and then calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Is there a way instead to have something like a BroadcastReceiver within the adapter that can keep track of the adapter item which started the network call or service? any maybe only respond to the receiver if the view is not currently recycled

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give an exact answer as your best approach since what you described is a really high level overview. I'll have to give an equal high level answer.  Hopefully it help.

There's not many ways around searching an `ArrayList` in the adapter for a given item.  One good idea:

You could create a custom adapter which is backed by an `ArrayList` but also maintains a `Set` of the data as well.  The benefit is finding an item is O(1) however any adds or removes require you to modify two collections instead of one...which will cause a slight slow down.  I've personally had to use this solution once for a highly complex adapter/listview. It could get updated quite often (*to the point throttling `notifyDataSetChanged()` was once discussed*) Surprisingly the slow down in maintaining a `List` and `Set` was hardly noticeable and overall worked well.

You could use a similar approach if your data has some sort of unique id associated with it. In which case you could build a `Map` of the data and use the maps `values()` method to obtain the `List` to use for the adapter. While using the keys to quickly find and update the required data. This may or may not be more difficult then the `Set` idea.  Further if you can get your data into a `SparseArray` (having a unique int for each item), then you could use a [SparseArrayAdapter](https://github.com/JaySoyer/Advanced-Adapters) which can get you O(log n) search times. Of course you loose the ability to sort your data in any meaningful way.

I'm not sure how viable the `BroadcastReceiver` idea is. I would see it more like each item's object instance would control the network request/response for itself, but that would seem tricky and odd. There's always the option of using a `CursorAdapter`.  Just store all your data to DB.  Have the network calls update the DB which can then be reflected within the `CursorAdapter`.